# ParallelSum in Mathematica 9 vs 10

Tags: parallelization

Here's part of a package I'm working on:

```
BeginPackage["TestPackage`"]

reduction::usage = "reduction[x] returns x after some rules have been applied.";

Begin["`Private`"]

auxReduction1[exp_]:=Module[{matched,pointsMatched},

If[StringMatchQ[ToString[exp,InputForm],{"*θ"~~DigitCharacter..~~"θ"~~DigitCharacter..~~"^2*"}]==True,
matched=ToExpression[StringCases[ToString[exp,InputForm],"θ"~~DigitCharacter..~~"θ"~~DigitCharacter..~~"^2"]];
pointsMatched=StringCases[ToString[matched[[1]]],"θ"~~x:DigitCharacter..->x];
(exp/.{matched[[1]]->1})(-(1/2)ToExpression["θ"~~pointsMatched[[1]]~~"sq θ"~~pointsMatched[[2]]~~"sq"]),

exp
]
]

(*This function allows the application of the previously defined function on a sum of terms*)
auxReduction2[exp_]:=Module[{auxList,i,ans},
auxList=Flatten[{Replace[exp,HoldPattern[Plus[a___]]:>{a}]}];(*Create list of the terms in the sum*)
ans=ParallelSum[auxReduction1[auxList[[i]]],{i,1,Length[auxList]},DistributedContexts->Automatic]
]

reduction[exp_]:=FixedPoint[auxReduction2,exp];

End[]

EndPackage[]
```

In Mathematica 9 this works just fine. In Mathematica 10, shadowing messages appear the first time I use the function defined in the package. For example, if I run

```
reduction[θ1θ2^2]
```

then I get the message

```
Global`θ1sq::shdw: Symbol θ1sq appears in multiple contexts {Global`,System`}; definitions in context Global` may shadow or be shadowed by other definitions.
```

and after it the expected answer.

Why is this happening in Mathematica 10 but not 9? By the way if `Sum` is used instead of `ParallelSum`, then everything works fine in both Mathematica 10 and 9.

Comment: I can confirm that both MMA 8 and 9 don't generate this error message and that MMA 10 does indeed yield this message. Looks like a bug to me. I'd suggest reducing this example to the bare bones, and submitting it to support@wolfram.com.